# How to run a specific function each time someone enters my website in go?

Tags: http, go

I'm using the following code:

```
func main() {

    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web-files")))

    http.HandleFunc("/auth/verify", verify)
    http.HandleFunc("/auth/login", login)
    http.HandleFunc("/auth/signup", signup)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I'm new to go and what I want to do is that every time someone enters my webpage a function named `updateCookies` runs.
I've tried to use `http.HandleFunc("/", updateCookies)` but it didn't work cause I have already used `http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web-files")))`

Thanks

Comment: you will need a middleware func for achieving  this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.Handle`, `http.HandleFunc`, and `http.ListenAndServe` (with `nil` as the second argument), use [`http.DefaultServeMux`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.19#DefaultServeMux) for routing the requests to their respective handlers.

`http.ListenAndServe` will use the default mux ONLY when the second argument passed to it is `nil`. If a non-nil argument is provided then it will use that, instead of the default mux, to handle the incoming requests.

Given that `http.ListenAndServe`'s second parameter's type is the `http.Handler` interface, you could simply pass `updateCookies` to `http.ListenAndServe` as the second argument (though you'll have to convert it explicitly to `http.HandlerFunc`) and then modify `updateCookies` to, at the end, pass the `w` and the `r` to the default mux.

```golang
func updateCookies(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // ... [your original cookie code] ...
    http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

// ...

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(updateCookies))
```

Answer (score 2):

The handler for the your application is [http.DefaultServeMux](https://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultServeMux).  Wrap that handler with another handler that executes your code:

```
// wrap returns an http.Handler that wraps another http.Handler
func wrap(h http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Before hook.
        updateCookies(w, r)

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)  // call the wrapped handler

        // After hook.
        // Nothing for now.
    }
}


func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web-files")))
    http.HandleFunc("/auth/verify", verify)
    http.HandleFunc("/auth/login", login)
        http.HandleFunc("/auth/signup", signup)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", wrap(http.DefaultServeMux))
}
```

I wrote the code to wrap an arbitrary handler because there's an easy transition to using your own [http.ServeMux](https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeMux):

```
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web-files")))
    mux.HandleFunc("/auth/verify", verify)
    mux.HandleFunc("/auth/login", login)
    mux.HandleFunc("/auth/signup", signup)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", wrap(mux))
}
```

Any package can register a handler in http.DefaultServeMux.  Creating your own mux ensures that you have complete control over the handlers running in your application.